# refund or replacement for a faulty product purchased online with mastercard?

Tags: online-payment, consumer-protection, refund, chargeback

I bought a product from a company located in Brooklyn, New Work, online and had the product shipped by them to me to Armenia.

The product was of unsatisfactory quality as it didn't function as expected. There was a lot of email exchanges between me and the company where I attached photos and videos clearly showing the problem. The company suggested a number of things to try to fix the problem, but none of them worked (and I've told them that). Lately I talked about this issue with other customers over an internet forum who had bought the same product from that company and all of them had that issue with the product.

Lately the company has stopped replying to my emails and before has ignored my email about getting a refund or replacement.
They have commented that "normally" they would have the product sent back to them for inspection. Shipping the product back would cost $200 (excl. tax/customs) and take about a month.

The product cost $700 + $200 shipping.

What can I do? Can I demand a refund from them, my bank, etc. or a replacement?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to check with your bank. The laws and regulations on this differ from country to country, and I'm sure there's some Armenian law on the issue.

If Armenia follows the EU legislation, then there's a case for charge-back in this case. But you'll have to go through your bank/credit card issuer for this.

Comment: isn't there a time limit for bank chargeback?

Comment: @redbaron there is. In most cases that would probably not be over 60 days.

Comment: chargeback is for the bank. is there anything for the company selling the faulty goods?

Comment: Chargeback instructs the bank to pull the money back out of the vendor's account and into yours. Of course if you abuse this you're legally liable... but if the vendor really hasn't delivered, it's one way to enforce a refund. However, you should always try to work it out with the vendor first, and chargeback is really applicable only if the product was not delivered at all. I; if it simply failed to meet expectations, you need to work that out with the vendor. If it was damaged in transit, the vendor should work that out with the delivery company and send you an exchange.

Comment: @redbaron the bank will not pay you from their own money, don't you worry. Charge-back goes all the way back to the merchant with added fines and penalties from their merchant services provider. You can always sue them in court, but if the company is in Brooklyn, NY - that's where you'll have to go to sue them.

Comment: @keshlam "not as expected" is one of the more common charge-back reasons, from my experience in the industry (granted I left that industry more than a decade ago).

Comment: @littleadv: You're probably right; I may be reflecting my own policies more than the banks.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Problem is it took the company more than 60 days just to get it shipped to me after charging me. So I'm afraid chargeback period has passed. What about the Office Of Attorney General-Consumer Affairs Dept. in the area of Brooklyn?

Comment: @redbaron you can try them, you can try BBB, you can try FTC - but only the courts can actually *force* the company refund you anything.

Comment: Thanks. I've just heard about that from someone else on the internet. Any ideas how to contct them? is there any point if I'm not in the/from US?

Comment: @redbaron Google is your friend. http://www.ag.ny.gov/bureau/consumer-frauds-bureau

Comment: Thank you. Now is there a point though if I'm not from the US? This could be a question on its own I guess.

Comment: I looked up chargeback in Russia (because I can't find the legal term in armenian) and there the time limit is 120 days, and from the **day of receiving the goods** , not paying, which makes more sense because shipping might in some cases and areas take more than 60 days. Is that also the case in US, or is it from the day of payment in US?

Comment: @redbaron what do you care what's in the US? You're in Armenia. Call your bank and ask.